# Spring Boot 2 JPA Exception translation With or Without Web/Rest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I am trying creating a JPA repo as follows, and facing few problems

- I want to translate all spring Exceptions to Business Exceptions as Service Layer (Not Web/Rest Service)
- All the examples and solution i come across on stackoevrflow and spring docs are related to web `@ControllerAdvice`, I want to be able to translate exception at service layer which can later be plugged into `@RestController` or `@Controller` if need be
- I think real challenge i am facing is to catch expcetions of all sorts

Repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, UUID>, Service<User, UUID> {

//@PreAuthorize("hasRole('W_USER')")
Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
```

}

and entitites are

```
<mapped-superclass class="xx.xx.BaseModel" access="FIELD">
    <attributes>
        <id name="uid">
            <column column-definition="BINARY(16)" />
            <generated-value strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>
        <basic name="creationDate">
            <column
                column-definition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
                insertable="false" updatable="false" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="modificationDate">
            <column
                column-definition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
                insertable="false" updatable="false" />
        </basic>
        <version name="version"></version>
    </attributes>
</mapped-superclass>

<entity class="xx.xx.User">
    <table name="USER">
        <index column-list="email,username,enabled"></index>
    </table>

    <attributes>
        <basic name="email">

        </basic>
        <basic name="firstName"></basic>
        ...
        <basic name="username" optional="false">
            <column unique="true"/>
        </basic>
        <basic name="email" optional="false">
            <column unique="true"/>
        </basic>

        <many-to-many name="roles" fetch="LAZY">

        </many-to-many>
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "all Spring Exceptions"? You have a repository and you will have PersistenceExceptionTranslator enable that already is encapsulating the Hibernate and SQL exception in a DataAccessException. Here you will find all the subclasses https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/package-summary.html

Comment: In my service Layer which is @Service a repository call delegator i want to generate error objects

Comment: You could create your own Aspect: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-annotation